# What is the best visualization to demonstrate Likert proportion differences between treatment groups?

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2, experiments

I ran a survey experiment a month or so ago and have been struggling to find the best way to visualize the proportions of Likert responses between the control and treatment groups. Brief context for the experiment is below:

- There are two treatment conditions: control (*T*<sub>0</sub>) and treatment (*T*<sub>1</sub>).
- The Likert responses available to participants were 1 to 5 (inclusive). They measured their self-reported expectations of something (exactly what is irrelevant), with low expectations being numerically low (1) and high expectations being numerically high (5).
- There were 5 questions per treatment group (A, B, C, D, and E), for a total of 10 questions. These questions were nearly identical; their differences are the independent variable.

I read [a piece](https://blog.datawrapper.de/divergingbars/) where the authors argue that 100% stacked bar charts (instead of [diverging stacked bar charts](https://blog.datawrapper.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/full-180306_divergent8.png)) are the best visualization for quickly comparing proportions. They provide the chart below as an example of how these types of visualizations effectively display differences in proportions:
[image]

The difficulty that I have had is figuring out how to create a visualization as effective as the one above that *also* shows differences between treatment groups. The only thing that I could think of was the visualiztaion below, where the cyan-red distinction communicates treatment group, and the brightness of each color represents the Likert value (darker being lower, brighter being higher):
[image]

However, I still feel like there is a better way to visualize what I am describing, but I'm spinning wheels and cannot think of any better ways. If anyone has any input on how to visualize this best, I greatly appreciate it.

PS: I am working in R with the tidyverse.